# How to retrieve records from multiple tables in ms-access?

Tags: java, swing, ms-access

I am trying to copy records into a JTable.
I have populated the JTable from one database table successfully.
Now I want to populate the JTable from two tables simultaneously.
I have `Call_Status` field in both tables i.e. `RMA_Master` & `Other`.
Now I want details of records having `call_Status == 'Open'` but it's throwing an error whenever I query the database.

My Query is:

```
String call_Status="Open";
String sql="Select * From RMA_Master,Other Where Call_Status='"+call_Status+"'";
```

And StackTrace is:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The specified field 'Call_Date' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.
```

Comment: and What is the Error ?

Comment: Please post the error stacktrace as well as the database structure

Comment: @vijay Exception: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The specified field 'Call_Date' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.

Comment: @NeerajJain I have explained the stacktrace now.

Comment: Where is stacktrace still not able to see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String call_Status="Open";
String sql="Select * From RMA_Master as r,Other as o Where r.Call_Status=o.Call_Status and r.Call_Status='"+call_Status+"'";
```

If this gives error, please post the error as well as your database schema.

Answer (score 0):

## Try

`Select * From RMA_Master as r,Other as o Where` `r.Call_Status='"+call_Status+"' and o.Call_Status='"+call_Status+"'";`

You need to access call_Status with **alias Name.**

Instead you can prefer **Inner Join**

`Select * from tableA as a inner join tableB as b on` `a.call_Status=b.call_Status where a.call_Status=call_Status`